# Me da el error en c++ al momento de compilar: 'While' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, dev-c++

```
#include <iostream>

/*Dado un número natural de 3 cifras, diseñe un programa que determine la suma de las cifras del número. Por ejemplo
Entrada: 
     Nro= 347
Salida
     Suma cifras = 14
*/

using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    int numero, suma, r;
    suma=0;
    cout<<"Ingrese numero: "<<endl;
    cin>>numero;
    While(numero>0){
        r=numero%10;
        numero=numero/10;
        suma=sumar+r;
    }
    
        
    cout<<"\nLa suma de digitos es: "<<suma<<endl;
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while` es con todo minusculas, tu tienes la primera mayuscula.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que he probado, el `While` lo tenias puesto con mayúscula la W, por lo cual no iba y en la suma tenias escrito `sumar` en vez de suma. Por el resto esta todo bien.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int numero, suma, r;
    suma=0;
    cout<<"Ingrese numero: "<<endl;
    cin>>numero;
    while(numero>0){
        r=numero%10;
        numero=numero/10;
        suma=suma+r;
    }


    cout<<"\nLa suma de digitos es: "<<suma<<endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While debe ir con minúsculas: `while`.

También en la línea 8, cambia sumar por `suma=suma+r`;

Answer (score 0):

El error puede estar en:

```
While(numero>0){
r=numero%10;
numero=numero/10;
suma=sumar+r;
}
```

te equivocaste al usar la variable suma, le pusiste sumar.
una manera de evitar este error es:

```
suma+=r;
```